# Different layout & functionality for fragments used by a viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm working with fragments and viewpager. I'd like to have a different layout and a different functionality per page. How can I accomplish this?
At the moment I have different layouts for every page, but I'm lacking to put functionality behind it. Can you help me with this?

MyFragment

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    int mCurrentPage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /** Getting the arguments to the Bundle object */
        Bundle data = getArguments();

        /** Getting integer data of the key current_page from the bundle */
        mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = null; //= inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container,false);
        //TextView tv = (TextView ) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        //tv.setText("You are viewing the page #" + mCurrentPage + "\n\n" + "Swipe Horizontally left / right");

        //changeing the layout per page here
        switch(mCurrentPage){

        case 1:
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container,false);
            break;

        case 2:
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_favorite, container,false);
            break;

        case 3:
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_settings, container,false);
            break;
        }    

       return v;
    }

}
```

MyFragmenterPagerAdapter

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

    /** Constructor of the class */
    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
        myFragment.setArguments(data);
        return myFragment;
    }

    /** Returns the number of pages */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of functionality are you looking to place?

Comment: All kind of functionality, get data from a server, using google maps, save data, connect with social media etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to have a different layout and a different functionality per page. How can I accomplish this?

Since you want different functionality and different layouts for each page, you should have a different `Fragment` for each page. In your `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
/** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            return new MyMainFragment();
        case 1:
            return new MyFavoritesFragment();
        case 2:
            return new MySettingsFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

And then in each `Fragment`, inflate each separate layout in `onCreateView`. For example, `MyMainFragment` it would look like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);

    return v;
}
```

This way, each `Fragment` (aka page) will behave as its own logical piece of UI, separate from the other pages.

Comment: When I do that, I'm getting the next error in my switch statement: **Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyMainFragment to Fragment**. By the way what should I put in the onCreateView of the class _MyFragment_

Comment: `MyMainFragment` has to extend `Fragment` (in order to be a `Fragment`, simple java), you must be missing that. Also, `MyFragment` is no longer needed. Before you were using it to try to show 3 pages, now you have 3 separate `Fragment`s that handle each page now.

Comment: Oops sorry, I'm kind of new to java and android :) Well Now the crashes when I go to the second screen.

Comment: @mXX it crashed mine also. have you solved this issue. I have implemented as suggested by the Steven Byle anser. please help me

Comment: If I remember correctly seemed like a project -> clean project solved the issue. But was a while back and didn't do any android development any more since then.